# Apache2: Problems matching accented characters in query string using RewriteCond & RewriteRule

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-rewrite, utf-8

Working on a site where the plan is to move URLs from a query string format to a number based format. Lots of URLs exist that have unescaped accented & similar UTF8 characters in them.  The problem?  I can’t seem to get Apache2 to properly match accented characters & do a rewrite. I am doing this all in the Apache2 config.

For example, this URL:

```
http://great.website.example.com/?place=cafe
```

Will work as expected with this Apache2 RewriteRule setting:

```
  RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(place|location)=cafe
  RewriteRule ^/find/$ /find/1234? [L,R=301]
```

Now look at this URL. Note the accented `é`:

```
http://great.website.example.com/?place=café
```

Why doesn’t that URL work with the following Apache2 RewriteRule setting:

```
  RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(place|location)=café
  RewriteRule ^/find/$ /find/1234? [L,R=301]
```

Both of these rules should rewrite the URL to the following:

```
http://great.website.example.com/find/1234
```

But the example with the accented `é` simply doesn’t work. Maybe a wildcard character would work, but I can’t seem to get that to work either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a RewriteMap to do the unescaping for you. like this:

```
RewriteMap unescape int:unescape

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING}  (location|place)=(.*)
RewriteCond ${unescape:%2}   café
RewriteRule ^/find/$         /find/1234? [L,R]
```

In the second RewriteCond line I use %2, as %1 would contain either "location" or "place".

However, adding a lot of RewriteRules to your config in order to map words to numbers is going to be a big performance hit on your server, and will be hard to maintain. A better solution is to use a RewriteMap for that too.

For example, asume that `/etc/apache2/places.txt` contains:

```
café    1234
shop   1235
...
```

Then this whould work for you:

```
RewriteMap unescape int:unescape
RewriteMap places   txt:/etc/apache2/places.txt

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING}  (location|place)=(.*)
RewriteCond ${unescape:%2}   (.*)
RewriteRule ^/find/$         /find/${places:%1}? [L,R]
```

You can also use a RewriteMap based on a database query. That would be my preferred choice, as I could then ofload the job of matching words to numbers to the content management system.

More details you can find in the documentation:
http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritemap

Comment: This doesn’t actually answer my initial question regarding the `é` mapping correctly, but this is a great idea I never knew about. Thanks for the tip!

Comment: ACtually if you just want to unescape strings just use the int:unescape rewritemap.

Comment: Okay, after playing around with this, this is clearly the superior answer.  Thanks for the  info!

Answer (score 1):

Your `/?place=café` will be [url-encoded](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp) by the browser to `/?place=caf%C3%A9` and this is what you should match.

Comment: Ahhh! UTF8! I have a script to generate the RewriteRule stuff that I then put into the Apache2 config & I forgot to set it to encode UTF8 prior to URL encoding it! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

In a [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9166744/how-do-i-get-apache-httpd-server-to-map-the-name-of-accented-html-elements-to-un), someone suggested using `RewriteMap` to call an external program to rewrite URLs.

Also:  Perhaps the request is actually something different entirely?  A browser might have internally translated the accented characters to url-encoded ASCII?  E.g. '`%20`' rather than ' '.